# Can't attach screen session

Tags: ubuntu, startup, gnu-screen

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS. I was trying to add java app (minecraft) to startup using init.d config. Here's a snippet:

```
MINECRAFT_DIR="/srv/minecraft-server"
START_COMMAND="java -Xincgc -Xmx8G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar Spigot.jar"
SCREEN_NAME="minecraft-server"

attach() {
    screen -Rx $SCREEN_NAME
}

start() {
    echo "Starting minecraft server..."
    if cd $MINECRAFT_DIR && screen -dmS $SCREEN_NAME $START_COMMAND; then
        echo "Minecraft server started. Use 'sudo service minecraft attach'."
    fi
}
```

When I issue `sudo service minecraft start` everything is fine, I can see the screen session in htop *and* `sudo screen -list` prints out the screen session. I also can attach it with `sudo service minecraft attach` or `sudo screen -x`.

But after `sudo update-rc.d minecraft defaults` and rebooting server, though I can see the screen session in htop, it is not listed in `sudo screen -list` and I can no longer attach it!

I tried using crontabs as root or my user with no success.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/9aEMWDNz) is my full init.d script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that you had to specify shell explicitly with

```
bash -c "cd $MINECRAFT_DIR && screen -dmS $SCREEN_NAME $START_COMMAND"
```

Or if you run it as user, you can

```
USERNAME='minecraft'
INVOCATION="cd $MINECRAFT_DIR && screen -dmS $SCREEN_NAME $START_COMMAND"
su - "$USERNAME" -s /bin/bash -c "$INVOCATION"
```

Thanks [this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script) for giving the idea.